# How can I add suggestions to TextFields in SwiftUI for MacOS (see gif below)?

Tags: macos, swiftui

This is the combo box effect I'm going for:

[image: Pop up combo box after choosing "Add Date", which shows several suggestions including "Today" and "Tomorrow"]

Any ideas are appreciated as this is my first SwiftUI project.

Comment: This is not something out-of-the-box in SwiftUI and I would suggest attempting something else for your first SwiftUI project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there nothing you can use out-of-the-box. I tried to create simple demo how you can create such a suggestion menu.

[SuggestionsDemo Project on GitHub](https://github.com/smic/SuggestionsDemo)

Comment: Wow! This is unbelievably helpful. Thank you so much. I just cloned it and am studying it now! 

Comment: It's got a bit of a bug which causes the suggestion dropdown to appear in two places. Is this only on my end?

Comment: The demo is not perfect. The information flow gives me some headaches. Take it as a start.